# How to change the UIStatus bar color?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to change the status bar color to Black translucent. I have changed my Info.plist 
UIStatusBarStyle
 UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent

And I have added these lines of code also to applicationDidFinishLaunching:()

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];

After doing these changes, my status bar changes to black translucent, till my splash screen appears. Once, my application is loaded fully and when the contents are displayed, it is again back to the default gray color.Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong or where i should change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on your info.plist and "Add Row". From there you can select what you want to add. There is a value called "Status bar style". Pick that. The corresponding value can also be pulled down and you can pick from gray, black with alpha .5, black.

Save, reload your app. That's all I had to do.

(I know the qn is 1 month old but I thought I'd leave the answer here anyway in case ppl search for it).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (2 tabs out of 5 in a root UITabBarController had gray looking status bar).  When I went and un-checked "Clip Subviews" for the main view of the controller for the tab that had the gray looking status bar, it "fixed" the problem as I was able to set my main background image to have a -20 "y" value so that the translucent status bar had something to be "translucent" over.

EDIT:

Turns out that what I really wanted to do was to set the "Wants Full Screen" option in IB (and/or `wantsFullScreenLayout` property in the VC for programmatically created VC) instead of turning off clipping and doing a negative offset.  This allowed me to see that I really did have a translucent status bar but had had layout problems so nothing was underneath it.

So if it appears that you have an other than black translucent status bar when you think you should have one, make sure that your views do layout underneath the status bar and it is not a visual effect that looks gray or black but in reality is just the lack of something to show through.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the `UIStatusBarStyle` key (also diplayed as "status bar style") in your app's Info.plist to `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent`.

Comment: Is this on iPhone or iPad? I don't think iPad supports `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent`.

Comment: This is in iphone only. As soon as my application gets loaded, it is showing only the default gray status bar