# To setStatusBarStyle when app is launching

Tags: iphone, ios, statusbar, launching

The status bar style is set as following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
}
```

But the status bar style when app is launching is `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` . How to set the status bar style while the app is launching? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go ot your project, Add a key value pair to the project-Info.plist

```
Key = UIStatusBarStyle
Value = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque
```

This will make the default status bar to UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque

for further info check the following
[How to change the UIStatus bar color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762013/how-to-change-the-uistatus-bar-color)