# How to change Ios Simulator Network symbol and Time and Charger indicator colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

Hi i am new for ios and in my `viewController` i have hidden `NavigationBar`

here i want to change simulator Network symbol and Time and Charger indicator colors in my app

please help how can we do this
i tried some code but not working

### code:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UINavigationBar *navigationBar      = [UINavigationBar appearance];
  navigationBar.tintColor             = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Status Bar text color in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the UIStatus bar color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762013/how-to-change-the-uistatus-bar-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Step 1*:

Open the `info.plist` file of your app and set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO`

[image]

*Step 2*: Next, in your `AppDelegate.m`, add this:

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

**Choice-2**

First, Go to `Project` -> `Target`,

Then set `Status Bar Style` to `Light`
[image: Project Setting]

and then set `View controller-based status bar appearance equal` to `NO` in `Info.plist`.

Comment: then it becomes white color bro?

Comment: Bro this line depricated  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent]; in ios 9

Comment: we can't customize the time and charger color, may be jailbroken device we can do, apart from we can't do anything, it is against to apple procedure